# Limit google analytic tracking code to one js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I recently implemented google analytic on my WordPress website, and I noticed that it includes multiple JavaScript files, such as:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?
```

I checked other websites, and don't see any of them having three google analytics scripts on the page.

Is there a way to limit this to only one file? All I need is the analytic stuff, I don't use tag management feature of google analytic.

I got the analytic code from Admin -> Tracking Info -> Tracking Code. and it looks like the following:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-"></script>
<script>
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-');
</script>
```

Comment: I think you're lacking an understanding on what's on your website.  As a simplified explanation, Google Tag Manager (GTM) allows you to implement tags and other scripts to fire on events that occur when your webpage is viewed or an interaction occurs.  It's not the same as standard Google Analytics (GA).  GA can be loaded through GTM. I do it on a few sites. If you don't want GTM to load, then you need to implement GA separately.  If you didn't set any of this up originally, you'll want to ask your original dev why they did it.  Eliminating GTM might impact some other functionality.

Comment: @JustinR. I am the one who set up the Google Analytic. I have updated my question to include the configuration. Do you see anything wrong with them? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to implement just the analytic feature. You can get the code from the link below and replace the tracking ID with your.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/